# Use different GoogleService-Info.plist for single project in xcode using swift4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, macros

I have a single project but with 4 different environments (Dev,Stagging,QA,Production). I have given their (environment's webservice url) paths from mobile's setting. Now I want to use different GoogleService-info.plist for all these different environments. Like when I select Dev from backend the project should take GoogleService-Info.plist of Dev project only. These GoogleService-Info.plists are created on 4 different accounts. Project should take the path of GoogleService-info.plist programmatically. I have tried the following code

1] By taking reference from [this](https://medium.com/@brunolemos/how-to-setup-a-different-firebase-project-for-debug-and-release-environments-157b40512164) url , I have created two folders Dev and QA (for now) and tried to given their paths by programmaically

```
#if DEV
    print("[FIREBASE] Development mode.")
    filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", 
ofType: "plist", inDirectory: "Dev")
    #elseif QA
    print("[FIREBASE] QA mode.")
    filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", 
ofType: "plist", inDirectory: "QA")
    #endif
    let options = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
```

But it throws an error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on

```
 let options = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
```

this line

2] Second I changed name of GoogleService-Info.plist by GoogleService-Info-QA.plist and tried to access this file programmatically

```
private func configureFirebase() {
    guard   let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: 
"GoogleService-Info-QA", ofType: "plist"),
        let options =  FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
        else { return }
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
}
```

But it throws an error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', 
reason: 'Failed to get default Firebase Database instance. Must 
call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) 
before using Firebase Database.
```

Comment: Your second error shows that you have not configured firebase in your appdelegate FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: yes its right, because I want to give the GoogleService-Info.plist path programatically. and compiler was not able to find that path. I dont know how to give that path programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I renamed GoogleService-Info.plists files by its respective environments. And Added those files in Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources. Then added the following code as per the environment selected

```
 guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "nameOfTheGoogleService-Info.plistFileAsPerTheEnvironment", ofType: "plist"),
                let options =  FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
                else { return }
            if FirebaseApp.app() == nil{
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
            }
```

Minor change is that, when user changes the app's environment, then he should remove app from background and open it again. Then the AppDeleagte takes the path of respective GoogleService-Info.plist as per its environment selected

Answer (score 1):

For this confirmation you have to follow following steps:

1. Goto Project Setting
2. Select you Dev Target
3. Goto Build Phase
4. Click on icon and create new run script with name GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST
5. use following script

```js
//Name of the resource we're selectively copying
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist

//Get references to dev and prod versions of the GoogleService-Info.plist
//NOTE: These should only live on the file system and should NOT be part of the target (since we'll be adding them to the target manually)
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/projectFolder/Firebase/Dev/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD=${PROJECT_DIR}/projectFolder/Firebase/Prod/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

//Make sure the dev version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"

if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV ]
then
echo "No Development GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
exit 1
fi

//Make sure the prod version of GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD ]
then
echo "No Production GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
exit 1
fi

//Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo "Will copy ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} to final destination: ${PLIST_DESTINATION}"

//Copy over the prod GoogleService-Info.plist for Release builds
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]
then
echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}"
cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
else
echo "Using ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}"
cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
fi
```

- Final Step: Make sure you have placed  GoogleService-Info.plist at correct location path in the project, You can find the attached image for reference.

GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_DEV=${PROJECT_DIR}/**projectFolder**/Firebase/Dev/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PROD=${PROJECT_DIR}/**projectFolder**/Firebase/Prod/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

**projectFolder** is your current project folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place this code snippet in your AppDelegate.swift in the application's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate function, somewhere before the `return true`

```
//Configure Firebase based on the app's environment
#if DEV
   guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-DEV", ofType: "plist") else { return }
   let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
   FIRApp.configure(with: options!)
#elseif QA
   guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-QA", ofType: "plist")  else { return }
   let options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
   FIRApp.configure(with: options!)
#endif
```

You need to make sure your plist files are named accordingly, and also make sure they are part of your target:

- Select the GoogleService-Info-DEV file and on the right, in the FileInspector make sure the checkbox is ticked for your app's target. Do the same with the GoogleService-Info-QA file.

Your files should be placed inside the main folder, as you would place a normal Google-Info.plist file.

Comment: You will need to change Active Compilation Conditions in the Targets -> Build Settings to your relevant Environment. 
Also the `FIRApp` is now changed to `FirebaseApp`.