# How to configure GoogleService TRACKING_ID programmatically?

Tags: ios, google-maps, configuration, plist

I am using Google Map Service in one of my iOS apps. I have two configurations `Development` and `Production`. Google Service `TRACKING_ID`s are different for both of the configurations so, every time when I prepare final AppStore version I need to change the `TRACKING_ID` from **`GoogleService-info.plist`** which is a repetitive manual work for me. I would like to know if that `TRACKING_ID` can be configured from source programmatically to avoid this manual checklist. I can detect configurations using macros but I do not know how I can override the **`.plist`** stuffs for Google service.

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626467/use-different-googleservice-info-plist-for-single-project-in-xcode-using-swift4

Comment: A lot tutorial for this problem available, I think you just google and find the way suitable for you. Example: https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0